# PHP: If record exists display HTML, else display nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to build a small customer database.

In my database, I have a column named "suspended_state" and the value can be either 'yes' or 'no' and if it's yes, I'd like it to show Suspended, if it's no I'd like it to display Active.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT suspend_state FROM tbl_company WHERE company_id='$company_id'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
if ($row['yes'])
echo "Suspended";
else {
echo "Active";
}

?>
```

However, all results come back as Active regardless of weather the column is 'yes' or 'no'

Please could someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Well... Is there any kindo of error displayed? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file to see any possible error and show us.

Comment: a lot of the times it helps to have `var_dump($row)` between `<pre></pre>` tags. That will dump all the contents of the array on your webpage and then you can see what you want to check against. Obviously you wouldn't want to leave that around for your final product.

Comment: Sidenote: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));` <= remove that semi-colon. Plus, use proper bracing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't selecting a column named 'yes'... and remove the ; as mentioned by Fred and add curly brackets as mentioned by BigScar try

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row['suspend_state'] == "yes") {
    echo "Suspended";
  } else {
    echo "Active";
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP's code needs a couple of brackets after the IF clause too.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) - Dont know how I didn't spot that column name! Been looking at it too long

Comment: A second set of eyes cuts debugging down by at least 75% ;-)  And this was a combo of 3 additional sets LOL